# slicing series of panels

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a simple dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,(20, 2)), columns=['col1','col2'])
>>> df['ind1'] = list('AAAAAABBBBCCCCCCCCCC')
>>> df.set_index(['ind1'], inplace=True)
>>> df

      col1  col2
ind1            
A        0     4
A        1     2
A        1     0
A        4     1
A        1     3
A        0     0
B        0     4
B        2     0
B        3     1
B        0     3
C        1     3
C        2     1
C        4     0
C        4     0
C        4     1
C        3     0
C        4     4
C        0     2
C        0     2
C        1     2
```

I am trying to get the rolling correlation coefficient of its two columns:

```
>>> df.groupby(level=0).rolling(3,min_periods=1).corr()

ind1
A    <class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: ...
B    <class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: ...
C    <class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: ...
dtype: object
```

The problem is that the result is series of panels:

```
>>> type(df.groupby(level=0).rolling(3,min_periods=1).corr())

pandas.core.series.Series
```

I am able to get desired coefficient for each row separately...

```
>>> df.groupby(level=0).rolling(3,min_periods=1).corr()['A']

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 10 (items) x 2 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
Items axis: C to C
Major_axis axis: col1 to col2
Minor_axis axis: col1 to col2

>>> df.groupby(level=0).rolling(3,min_periods=1).corr().loc['A'].ix[2]

          col1      col2
col1  1.000000 -0.866025
col2 -0.866025  1.000000

>>> df.groupby(level=0).rolling(3,min_periods=1).corr().loc['A'].ix[2,'col1','col2']

-0.86602540378443849
```

...but I don't know how to slice the result (series of panels) in order to assign the results as a column to existing dataframe.  Something like:

```
df['cor_coeff'] = df.groupby(level=0).rolling(3,min_periods=1).corr()['some slicing']
```

Any clues? Or a better way to get rolling correlation coefficients?

Comment: This is a well-written question - it's got everything necessary to replicate the issue, it shows what you've tried so far, and it shows your idea about what you'd like the solution to look like.  Nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that [`.corr()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.corr.html) is being called without specifying the `other` argument.  Even though your dataframe only has two columns, Pandas doesn't know which correlation you actually want, so it calculates all possible correlations (`col1` x `col1`, `col1` x `col2`, `col2` x `col1`, `col2` x `col2`) and gives the results to you in a 2x2 datastructure.  If you want to get the results from one correlation, you need to specify the correlation you want by setting the base column and the `other` column.  If you weren't using `groupby` you'd just do it this way:

```
df['col1'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=3).corr(other=g['col2'])
```

Since you're using `groupby`, you need to nest it in an `apply` clause with a lambda function (or you could move it into a separate function if you preferred):

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda g: g['col1'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=3).corr(other=g['col2']))
```